# splitting dataset of pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel, dataframe

How I can split the dataset programmatically. The dataset attached can be read using pandas. For understanding purpose I changed the background color of the dataset which I want to split from the main file. I can do that manually but its tedious so in python code how I can do that. The link for the dataset is provide below.
[text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q92b9f-fQO8xfheLaBZ57HYv3iJ-t80J/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100762354030800240063&rtpof=true&sd=true)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

I a trying to split my dataset which I have attached. For understanding purpose I have changed the background color of the dataset which I want split from main dataset using python code.

Comment: The exact logic is not fully clear, but you seem to want to split per group, so use `[g for _,g in df.groupby(your_groups)]`